# Determine capacitor value gives amplifier characteristic independent of frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, frequency-response

I have an amplifier for the needle EMG electrodes signal like image below. The question is : **Determine the C2 capacitor value gives electrode–amplifier characteristic independent of frequency**. Can you help me how to determine that value?

[image: EMG Amplifier]

I very appreciated with your support.

Comment: Any value except one will give characteristics dependent of frequency. Surely you mean *independent* of frequency, for which there's only one value.

Comment: Haizz, sorry it indepedent, I mistakenly typed. Can you help me to define that value. Thank you very much.

Comment: Imagine that R2 had a value R1 then, what value would C2 have?

Comment: If R2=R1, C2 will equal to C1 in order to make amplifier characteristic not depend on frequency. At this point Vi = 1/3Es. But I thinks R2 might not hold the same value with R1.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Finally, I found the answer. It would be C2 = C1*R1/R2.

Answer (score 0):

Resistors alone make a voltage impedance divider.

Capacitors alone make a voltage impedance divider.

- (common practice i scope 10:1 probes and 100k:1 HVAC voltage sensing bushings.)

Z(f) for RC source therefore must match Z(f) load ratio for RC net impedance divider for matched flat attenuator.

- I'll let you do the simple math.  Normally R2>>R1

## -  for added bonus

- estimate tolerances on R1//C1 and for a fixed   R2, what is tolerance error on C2's effect on attenuation error vs f?
- assume average saline-presoaked needles for 15 minutes are 1.4 megohms  at 10Hz to 6.6 kolohms  at 10kHz.
- What is optimal C2 R2 and tolerance sensitivity at 10kHz? from R1C1?  per unit  or per % error on BW?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Wish you have a good day.